# Employer providing uncomfortable PPE (safety footwear)

Tags: united-kingdom, law, safety

We are in the UK and a friend of mine is changing roles within her job into one in which she has to wear non-slip safety shoes (PPE - Personal Protective Equipment). The standard shoes that my employer provides give her a bad back, possibly as they are not supportive enough. She has tried some good-quality insoles of my own, but these do not help enough.

She has offered to buy her own shoes, but my employer says that this is not acceptable.

I've searched for UK legislation on this, but can't find anything that helps her with regard to her being made to wear the shoes they supply. She is not disputing having to wear approved shoes.

How can she approach her employer about getting an alternative shoe choice approved?

Edit: Getting a medical note from a doctor would not be a problem. I know that employers have to supply suitable ergonomic etc equipment and we are wondering where this requirement and the PPE legislation cross over.

Comment: Has your friend visited a doctor with these problems? A doctor's note will almost certainly fix this issue.

Comment: Make sure she's asking the right question.  She first needs to show the shoes she wants to buy comply with the prevailing regulations.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings Maybe, but this is not about me and the question reflects the actual situation. I don't really want my manager coming to me asking what my shoe issue is.

Comment: @erik She can almost certainly get a note, but what do you think the outcome will be? Will her employer then allow her to supply her own PPE footwear do you think?

Comment: @SteveIves - Thats not how SE works but good luck to you.  Your problem is going to be too company specific to work with.

Comment: @Johns-305 I don't think they were objecting to the footwear she wanted; rather objecting from a rigidly bureaucratic "This is the list" point-of-view.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings I don't remember seeing anything about questions must be based on personal situations, Just that there should be a definite question with a (potentially) definite answer.

Comment: @SteveIves -  **You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face**   -
 https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings That's what I've done - my problem is that a friend of mine might not be able to take up a role she wants. This is a very practical, answerable question.

Comment: @SteveIves - A very practical question for your friend to ask...  But its all company specific or legal advicey...

Comment: Protections exist for pre-existing medical conditions and PPE which causes problems in healthy adults ([pg14](http://www.hse.gov.uk/pUbns/priced/l25.pdf)). This makes me think there's a fair case for accommodation, but self-bought PPE is probably never going to happen.

Answer (score 2):

> How can she approach her employer about getting an alternative shoe
>   choice approved?

She can always simply *ask* if an alternative shoe could be approved. She can mention her problem with the standard offering, and show her doctor's note.

Remember however, that the employer is still on the hook for the appropriateness of the safety footwear. They will likely be reluctant to let folks just pick out whatever shoe they prefer.

Some employers have a catalog of pre-approved choices for safety equipment, from which employees can choose. Others don't offer such a choice.

And "comfort" is not a requirement mandated by the government rules, as far as I can tell.

(I'm not an expert on UK law, but have worked for a company with a significant UK presence.)

Comment: Agreed, back when I worked in a construction company, comfort isn't also a priority for the workers. Safety is.

Comment: Doctors note is a good idea.  What's the point of protecting her feet when her back is now impacted.  So much for safety.

Comment: Comfort **is** a safety/welfare issue - or more precisely discomfort is.

Comment: The question doesn't say the shoes are uncomfortable, but that they are giving the wearer back pain.